# WinAPI: How to programmatically determine what network profile applies to a given network interface?

Tags: windows, winapi, network-programming

I'm trying to determine the NLM network profile (ie. the GUID in "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\") that is in use based on a given network interface.

I can't seem to find a relationship between these entities, other than enumerate all default gateways in the route table, check ARP cache/NetTable entries for the MAC address of each default route and then enumerate all managed/unmanaged NLM profiles looking for a DefaultGatewayMac which matches a MAC address in the NetTable. It seems very convoluted, surely Windows has an easier way to determine this?

Comment: [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx) and [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) can tell you the gateways assigned to each network adapter, and which network interfaces those adapters belong to. Note that on Vista+, `GetAdaptersAddresses()` also provides a `NetworkGuid` for each adapter. Maybe that is the same GUID you are looking for?

Comment: Best I can tell the NetworkGuid returned there is HwProfileGuid + 1 on the first octet, it doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the registry. Took me a while to not think I was going insane. Unfortunately that's not it.